# TableLayoutPanel not distributing rows and columns while hosted in TabPage

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a TableLayoutPanel that behaves itself on sizing its cells. However moving that TableLayoutPanel to a TabPage of a TabControl makes the column sizes not behave correctly, the last row and column are both seemingly autosize.

Is there any reason this should be the case?

VB.net in VS Express 2013

Comment: If it's not working then you have almost certainly done something wrong. If you don't tell us what you've done then we can't tell you what's wrong with it. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then update your question accordingly. Once we have an example that we can test for ourselves, we'll be able to see for ourselves whether you have done something wrong and, if so, what it is.

Comment: What does *a TableLayoutPanel that behaves itself on sizing its cells* mean? It looks like it's setup to auto-size itself. So, *the last row and column are both seemingly autosize* doesn't explain what might be the problem. -- A couple of images could be useful. Also a description of the TLP configuration. -- Note that Controls added to a TabPage that is not shown do not create their handles: this affects the LayoutEngine. How, in this case, it's not clear.

Comment: Jimi I've only just re-discovered that controls are added to the layout collection, then the layout takes care of itself. I think the absence of controls in the layout might have been causing it in the designer.